# Add multiple variables to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My data is as below:

```
    gvkey   datadate fyear     cusip curcd     at    ceq  csho   dltt dvc  nopi oibdp prstkc
1:  1001 12/31/1981  1981 000165100   USD     NA     NA    NA     NA  NA    NA    NA     NA
2:  1001 12/31/1982  1982 000165100   USD     NA     NA    NA     NA  NA    NA    NA     NA
3:  1001 12/31/1983  1983 000165100   USD 14.080  7.823 3.568  4.344   0 0.640 2.650  0.000
4:  1001 12/31/1984  1984 000165100   USD 16.267  8.962 3.568  4.181   0 0.575 3.208  0.000
5:  1001 12/31/1985  1985 000165100   USD 39.495 13.014 3.988 11.908   0 0.623 7.247  0.009
6:  1003 12/31/1981  1981 000354100   USD     NA     NA    NA     NA  NA    NA    NA     NA
   pstkrv prcc_c year          REP
1:     NA     NA 1981           NA
2:     NA     NA 1982           NA
3:      0  7.250 1983           NA
4:      0  3.750 1984 0.0000000000
5:      0 10.125 1985 0.0002278769
6:     NA     NA 1981           NA
```

I want to add several variables that are based on the existing ones, and my code is as below:

```
Compustat.1<-Compustat.1[,  `:=`(DIV= dvc/at,
                                REPR= REP/(REP+DIV),
                                PCASH= oibdp/at,
                                TCASH= nopi/at,
                                CASHVOL= data.table::shift(rollapply(PCASH,5,FUN=sd,fill=NA,align="right"),1,fill=NA),
                                SIZE= at,
                                LEV= dltt/at,
                                MB= prcc_c*csho), 
                                by=cusip]
```

I kept receiving the error message

```
 Error in `[.data.table`(Compustat.1, , `:=`(DIV = dvc/at, REPR = REP/(REP +  : 
  object 'DIV' not found
```

Since I have already defined the variable DIV at the first step, I could not figure out what the issue is.

Comment: The error should come from `REPR= REP/(REP+DIV)`. `DIV` is defined in the `Compustat.1` before running the whole assignment statement, that's why it is not found.

Comment: how can i fix this issue?

Comment: You can do `DIV = DIV <- dvc/at` and similar for any other cols that get reused later, like PCASH, I think. The feature request for what you're attempting is over here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/659

Comment: Sorry for typo, `DIV` is NOT defined in the Compustat.1 before running the whole assignment statement.

Comment: Based on the example the `CASHVOL` returns all NA.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this within `{}`

```
Compustat.1[, c("DIV", "REPR", "PCASH", "TCASH", "SIZE", "LEV", "MB")  := 
            {DIV <- dvc/at
            REPR <- REP/(REP+DIV)
            PCASH <- oibdp/at
            TCASH <- nopi/at
          #CASHVOL <- data.table::shift(rollapply(PCASH,5,FUN=sd,fill=NA,align="right"),1,fill=NA)
           SIZE <- at
           LEV <- dltt/at
           MB  <-  prcc_c*csho
          .( DIV, REPR, PCASH, TCASH, SIZE, LEV, MB)}, by=cusip]
```

Comment: Could you add the data to the OP or here? I've never seen this usage and want to figure out how it works.

Comment: Can I use '=' instead of '<-' ?

Comment: @Bobo You could use that, but it is better to use `<-`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are making a reference to DIV when it hasn't been created yet. Given that the formula for DIV seems to be easy, I would suggest copying it directly in the formula for REPR. Same for PCASH. Also, note that assigning Compustat.1 is not necessary because ':=' creates the variables in place:

```
Compustat.1[,  `:=`(DIV= dvc/at,
                    REPR= REP/(REP + dvc/at),
                    PCASH= oibdp/at,
                    TCASH= nopi/at,
                    CASHVOL= data.table::shift(rollapply(oibdp/at,5,FUN=sd,fill=NA,align="right"),1,fill=NA),
                    SIZE= at,
                    LEV= dltt/at,
                    MB= prcc_c*csho), 
                    by=cusip]
```

Should work well,